# Running separate programs securely

Tags: security, users

I basically will be running multiple programs which might try to do something malicious (like delete files outside of their given directories). So I think I need to run the programs as a user who can only access a given location (there are files which it needs to access), while not allowing it to access any other directories. But from what I have read it's very hard to completely lockout a user so I am a bit lost on what to do.
Many thanks.

Comment: Take a look at **firejail** (https://www.tecmint.com/firejail-run-untrusted-applications-in-linux/).

Comment: Or run the program in a disposable container or a VM.

Comment: Would set up a VM and copy any files needed over to it.  Keeps your main system and files safe.